# Getting User.Identity is Forms using FormsAuthentication in ASP.NET 4.5

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I am using FormAuthencation in my current web application with ASP.NET 4.5. I have placed a check on Login page `if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated){ }` then redirect to main page , but strange **without** even login i am getting `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = true` i do not understand why that giving **true**.

Web.Config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" name=".ASPNETAUTH" defaultUrl="~/Account/Welcome.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30" path="/"></forms>
    </authentication>
```

Thanks
Ravi Mittal

Comment: Could you show your code for login and possible even in web config? Sounds like you might not be denying unauthenticated users.

Comment: There are multiple reasons why this may occur.  What does your web config section look like?  in particular the Authorization section? Also a previous authorization cookie may be cached by the browser.  Is the Name property populated?

Comment: Can you specify if you are using ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Web Forms?  Forms authentication behaves differently in MVC that it does on Web Forms

Comment: @AgustinCoder: forms authentication doesn't behave differently in web forms vs mvc. In fact, it would be deeply confusing if it did.

Comment: @WiktorZychla there are minor differences that can affect the behavior for example in MVC forms authentication depends on the existence of the AuthorizationAttribute action filter, if this filter is not enabled even if the forms authentication is enabled at the web.cofig level it will not work as expected.  The authentication process also occurs at different stages within the ASP.NET pipeline.

Comment: Here is an old article mentioning some of the gotchas in MVC vs WebForms http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/04/18/asp-net-mvc-authentication-global-authentication-and-allow-anonymous.aspx

Comment: @AgustinCoder: now you are more specific but note that you mention authorization. Yes, there are differences in the way you apply authorization and still the forms authentication behaves in the same exact way as it is handled by the very same authentication module.

Comment: @Ravi: what is the output of `User.Identity.GetType()`?

Comment: @WiktorZychla you are correct forms authentication is handled by the same module.  What dictates the difference is if it is triggered by access to a physical file or the authorizeattribute action filter either way redirects to the login page occour upon the first issuance of the HTTP 401 status code.

Comment: @WiktorZychla : i will try this code snippet and let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is published in IIS, you need to disable anonymous access via IIS (you can see how to do that [on this page](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/anonymousauthentication)).

It would also help to make sure the  [`<authorization>` section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d82143t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) of your web.config has something like this:

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

This will block "unauthorized" users from your app.